# Best Option for Queuing Status Updates .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, service-broker

I'm looking for some feedback in regards to the best option for a problem I am working on.

To give you some background I recently inherited a broken business application (our project was using it, so we gained responsibility to fix it), I come from a SharePoint development background so a little C#, ASP.NET and SQL.

Currently we have an issue with the application where we continually receive timeout errors, I have narrowed it down to the web application calling a bunch of stored procedures to update status fields in other tables when something changes that might affect the status of other objects.

Without completely overhauling this application I have determined our best option is to offload these stored procedures to run in the background and not be tied to the UI. I've looked at a couple of options including:

- Creating a separate thread to handle the execution. (Still times out)
- Using BackgroundWorker (still times out, obviously it shouldn't but I can't seem to find out what is causing it to wait for the BackgroundWorker to finish)
- Moving the Stored Proc execution to a job, which I then call from another SP. (This works, but the limitation is that I can only have one job running at once, and if multiple users update objects they then receive an exception because the job won't start)

Right now we have moved these stored procedures into a twice a day script, which updates all objects, however this is only a temporary fix.

I have two options that I'm looking at, and I'm hoping to get some guidance on the implementation of whatever you consider to be the best option:

- Continue using the job and have the executing stored proc queue up items in a db which the job will loop through until empty. The executing stored proc will have to check if the job is running when it adds a new entry and then act accordingly.
- It's been recommended that I look at using the Service Broker, but I am not familiar with it's use at all. I understand that it would likely be a better overall solution, as it allows me to queue up these updates in a more transactional way.

I think both these options are viable although I need some help in understanding the implementation of the second option. My other dilemma is with these stored procedures running anywhere from 45s to 20m how can I notify the user that changed the object that his/her updates have been made? This is where I fallback to using the job because i could simply add a user field into the 'queue' and have the stored proc send a quick email at the end.

Thoughts, suggestions? Maybe I'm over-thinking this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on .NET 4.5 and C# 5.0 use async and if you are on .NET 4.0 use TPL. They have the same underlying (almost) and async feature is built upon TPL (with some extra internals).

In any case TPL would be a proper choice.

Comment: you are referring to doing something like `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DAL.UpdateComptuerStatusByApplicationID(originalApplication.AutoNumber), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`
I had tried this and was getting a timeout on the sql connection, so I increased the timeout threshold but the UI would still hang until this completed, often causing ASP to time out. Is it because I have this nested in another function that makes the calls to update the actual object before calling the stored proc to update the status?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Service Broker would be an excellent solution to this problem. It's true that there is a bit of a learning curve to climb to get your head round how it works, but it's fundamentally pretty simple especially when your implementation is in a single database.

There's a good (and mercifully short) intro to how it works at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345108(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Asynchronous Procedure Execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/). But I would look first if the updates can be improved, perhaps a simple index can eliminate the timeouts, and/or try to leverage [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). These would be much simpler to try out w/o committing to  'major overhaul' of the application code.

I must also urge you to read [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). This is a SQL Server methodology for identifying performance bottlenecks. Is a great way of narrowing down the problems of 'timeouts' to something more actionable (blocking, IO, indexes etc).